# My application usage memory remained high even after clear all my objects list

Tags: wpf

So i have this `Base Class`:

```
public abstract class WiresharkFile : IDisposable
{
    private string _fileName;
    private int _packets;
    private int _packetsSent;
    private string _duration;
    private double _speed;
    private int _progress;
    protected abstract WiresharkFilePacket ReadPacket();
    public abstract IEnumerator<WiresharkFilePacket> GetEnumerator();
    public abstract void Rewind();

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set { _fileName = value; }
    }

    public int Packets
    {
        get { return _packets; }
        set { _packets = value; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // implemented inside sub class.
    }
}
```

And specific `Wireshark` format (libpcap):

```
public class Libpcap : WiresharkFile, IDisposable, IEnumerable<WiresharkFilePacket>
{
    private BinaryReader binaryReader;
    private Version version;
    private uint snaplen;
    private int thiszone;
    private uint sigfigs;
    private LibpcapLinkType linktype;
    private long basePos;
    private bool byteSwap;
    private static uint MAGIC = 0xa1b2c3d4;
    private static uint MAGIC_ENDIAN = 0xd4c3b2a1;

    public Libpcap(string path)
        : this(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        FileName = path;
    }


    private Libpcap(Stream fileStream)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override void Rewind()
    {
        binaryReader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        binaryReader.BaseStream.Position = basePos;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (binaryReader != null)
            binaryReader.Close();
    }
```

> I removed almost all parts of how i am read this file

**Add files in to my application**

I have this objects list:

```
public ObservableCollection<WiresharkFile> wiresharkFiles { get; set; }
```

This list is binding into my `ListView`.

When the user choose files to add into my application:

```
string[] files = openFileDialog.FileNames;
```

I am check this files via another class:

```
public class FileValidation
{
    public static void DoWork(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(files,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
                },
            file =>
            {
                ProcessFile(file);
            });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }

        }, tokenSource.Token,
           TaskCreationOptions.None,
           TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith
            (t =>
            {
                if (FinishValidationEventHandler != null)
                    FinishValidationEventHandler();
            }
    , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
    }

    private static void ProcessFile(string file)
    {
         ReadWiresharkFormat(file);
         using (WiresharkFile wiresharkFile = new Libpcap(file))
         {
             WiresharkFileInfo.ReadInfo(wiresharkFile);
             // Add file into my list.
         }
    }

    private static WiresharkFileFormat ReadWiresharkFormat(string file)
    {
        using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
        {
            // Open file and read first 4 bytes in order to verify file type.
        }
    }

    private static void ReadInfo(WiresharkFile wiresharkFile)
    {
        foreach (WiresharkFilePacket packet in wiresharkFile)
        {
            // Collect file information (number of packets...)
        }                
    }
}
```

OK so until here all good.
Now when add many files, lets say (1000+-) i can see that my memory usage is growing in 200MB but after clear this list the memory usage not changed.
Any idea what could cause this ?

Comment: Have a look at the .NET managed memory performance counters to see if you are "leaking" managed memory. "Memory usage" is a pretty vague metric anyway. For instance, Windows has a concept called _working set_ but the working set will only be trimmed if required by Windows.

Comment: i can see that most of the memory is specific method that read the file bytes inside Libpcap class, but i am do this with using so what could cause this ?

Comment: Calling `Dispose()` on an `IDisposable` object does not free managed memory (but should free unmanaged memory). Only the garbage collector will free managed memory. But even if the managed memory is freed the process might retain the allocated memory from the OS point of view. That is why I recommend that you have a look at the managed memory performance counters to understand if you have a problem. Perhaps you are suffering from LOH fragmentation but it is hard to know without facts.

Comment: What could cause if the process retain the allocated memory from the OS ?